# How to trim transparent space in UIImageView?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have an app that can drag images anywhere in the view but my problem is that when the other image is behind to the other there is no way to move directly the image behind than moving the above image. I found only trimming `UIImage` but it will display still in `UIImageView` as rectangle. I would like to trim the white space so I can click directly behind images.

How can I trip `UIImageView` transparent space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bitmap and then examine each pixel. You will find code to do this here. Once you know the exact dimensions you can use a Quartz `CGImageRef` function to extract out a smaller image from the larger one.

That said, you can add a gesture recognizer and use say double tap as a signal to move an image to the bottom of the view stack. I believe this is a much better solution if I were to use your app.

Comment: i have tried this but still when I set my `UIImageView` to this `UIImage` I still get that transparent rectangle side on my `UIImageView`.

Comment: You tried the first suggestion? If so don't look at RGB so much as alpha. When a is 0 the RGB values don't matter. Trim everything that is either alpha < 0.1 or where all RGB are > 250.

Comment: got it, the problem now is the transparent space. I have trip the image so i got my custom shape on `UIImage`. is there anyway I can have my desired shape to my `UIImageView` ?

Comment: UIImageView takes an image that has a defined square size. The way people show irregular shapes is with transparent pixels, or black, or white. The old Mac supported irregular images but not OSX.